# combine multi-dimensional array on value from JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have 2 api end points that load JSON data... 
1. subject matter experts

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ExpertiseId] => 1
            [IndustryId] => 1
            [PersonId] => 3
        )
...
)

1. people database
   Array
   (
   [0] => Array
       (
           [Id] => 1
           [Name] => Joe
           [Office] => New York
       )
   ....
   )

I'd like to pass both functions into an array, specify to merge on [matter.PersonId] => [people.Id] so the returned array would become

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ExpertiseId] => 1
            [IndustryId] => 1
            [PersonId] => 3
            [Id] => 1
            [Name] => Joe
            [Office] => New York
        )
...
)

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over both arrays and reorganize the data in such a way that merging can happen. In practice that means rekeying the first array by `PersonId` and the second by `Id`; this is very easy to do with [`array_column`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$matter = array_column($matter, null, 'PersonId');
$people = array_column($people, null, 'Id');
```

At this point only a simple task is left: merging the items (arrays) that share the same key in both `$matter` and `$people`.

In a perfect world that would be an one-liner with [`array_merge_recursive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php), but that function does not actually merge arrays that have integer keys like these (the ids we used as keys are integers). So a little standard iteration is in order: pick one of the arrays and merge its contents with the other:

```
foreach ($people as $id => $data) {
    // If there's a guarantee that both arrays will definitely have the same
    // set of keys (ids) so that $matter[$id] is guaranteed to exist,
    // you can also use the simpler: $matter[$id] += $data 
    $matter[$id] = isset($matter[id]) ? $matter[$id] + $data : $data;
}
```

...and now `$matter` has all the data merged together.

Answer (score -1):

Try array_merge()

$newArray = array_merge(first_array, second_array);